# Convert java code to coldfusion code (CFIMAP)

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to setup a connection to an office365 mailbox. This function is based on a java example (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28689722/2482184). I am almost done but i cannot figure out how to convert the following line of code which is in the orignal java example:

```
Message[] messages = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
```

Below the full function:

```
<cfscript>
    mailSettings = {};
    mailSettings.server = "outlook.office365.com";
    mailSettings.port = "993";
    mailSettings.username = "xxxx";
    mailSettings.password = "xxxx";
    mailSettings.action = "";
    mailSettings.folder = "INBOX";
    mailSettings.timeout = 5000;

    properties = createObject("Java","java.util.Properties");
    jsession = createObject("Java","javax.mail.Session");
    store = createObject("Java","javax.mail.Store");
    message = CreateObject("Java", "javax.mail.Message");

    properties.init();
    properties.put("mail.store.protocol","imap");
    properties.put("mail.from", mailSettings.username);
    properties.put("mail.imap.port", mailSettings.port);
    properties.put("mail.imap.connectiontimeout",mailSettings.timeout);
    properties.put("mail.imap.timeout",mailSettings.timeout);
    jsession = jsession.getInstance(properties);

    store = jsession.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect(mailSettings.server, mailSettings.username, mailSettings.password);

    inbox  = store.getFolder("#mailSettings.folder#");
    inbox.open( inbox.READ_ONLY );

    /**********
    NEED HELP TO CONVERT THIS LINE BELOW TO COLDFUSION SYNTAX
    ---------
    Message[] messages = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
    ---------
    END NEED HELP
    **********/

    inbox.close(true);

</cfscript>
```

I know there is a cfimap tag. I am trying to find a faster method to download emails.

Comment: Feel free to post the final code as an answer, so it's easier to spot. For speed, have you tried a FetchProfile? From the little I've read, might improve speed of getting headers https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238586/8895292

Comment: @Ageax I have been playing around with the Fetch method But i had no luck properly implementing this method. In my answer below you can see what i have tried and what should work imo. However the function does not improve in speed.

Comment: What is doing wrong, error or somethin else?

Comment: @Ageax No error message. From what i read the local.java.folder.fetch(local.java.messages, local.java.profile); method should download all the messages. Then outputting the subject (local.java.folder.getMessage(local.settings.x).getSubject()) should not require another roundtrip to the office365 server but output the data from cache. However the subject is not retrieved from cache, but downloaded from the office365 server (confirmed using a network sniffer).

Comment: FetchProfile is optional, so it's not always supported. Don't think you need "folder.getMessage(local.settings.x)".  If I understand correctly, fetch(...) already populates the array of messages, so just call getSubject() on each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a reference to [`Flag.SEEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Flags.html)

> `Flags.Flag` - This inner class represents an individual system flag.

Then use it to build the other objects (Flags and FlagTerm):

```
Flag = createObject("java", "javax.mail.Flags$Flag");
Seen = createObject("java", "javax.mail.Flags").init(Flag.SEEN);
Term = createObject("java", "javax.mail.search.FlagTerm").init(Seen, false);
// do search ...
messages = inbox.search(Term);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a MailFetch.java file.

```
imports ....
.....

public class MailFetch {

public function fetchFolder(String server, String port, String username, String password, String foldername){


    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties( ));
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect(server, port, username, password);
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder(foldername);
    inbox.open( Folder.READ_ONLY );

    ....

    code goes here 

    .....

    return messages; // Message[]

}
```

}

Compile the file using javac

- Start Command Prompt.
- Navigate to the folder that holds your class files:

  C:>cd \mywork
- Set path to include JDK’s bin.  For example:

  C:\mywork> path c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;%path%
- Compile your class(es):

  C:\mywork> javac *.java
- Create a manifest file and your jar file:

  C:\mywork> jar cvfm Craps.jar manifest.txt *.class

copy the jar to \ColdFusion\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib or \ColdFusion\cfusion\lib

restart Coldfusion service

Access using

```
mailobj = createObject("java","com.your.path.MailFetch");

messages = mailobj.fetchFolder("outlook.office365.com", "993", "xxxx", "xxxx", "INBOX");
```

you can try this also

```
<cfexchangeConnection action="open" username="xxxx" password="xxxx" port="993" server="outlook.office365.com" connection="testconn1">

<cfexchangemail action="get" name="inbox" connection="testconn1" folder = "INBOX"></cfexchangemail>

<cfexchangeConnection action="close" connection="testconn1">
```

Comment: Did not know the cfexchangeConnection tag so +1 for pointing me to that direction. Apparently office365 needs the version argument for the cfexchangeConnection tag. This argument is not avaible on cf9  (cf10 and upwards), the version I am currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Below the actual function i have written, partly based on Ageax answer. It is way faster then CFIMAP but still not as fast as i would like it to be. Implementation of the fetch method could really speed things up. I placed my implementation of the fetch command between /* */ because it does not work. I guess i am doing something wrong. If someone knows how to properly implement this method i would be very grateful.

```
<cfscript>
function fecthImap()
{
    var local = {};

    local.settings = {};
    local.settings.server = "outlook.office365.com";
    local.settings.port = "993";
    local.settings.username = "xxxx";
    local.settings.password = "xxxx";
    local.settings.action = "";
    local.settings.folder = "INBOX";
    local.settings.timeout = 5000;
    local.settings.tick = GetTickCount();
    local.settings.x = 1;

    local.java = {};
    local.java.properties = createObject("Java","java.util.Properties");
    local.java.properties.init();
    local.java.properties.put("mail.store.protocol","imap");
    local.java.properties.put("mail.from", local.settings.username);
    local.java.properties.put("mail.imap.port", local.settings.port);
    local.java.properties.put("mail.imap.connectiontimeout",local.settings.timeout);
    local.java.properties.put("mail.imap.timeout",local.settings.timeout);

    local.java.session = createObject("Java","javax.mail.Session");
    local.java.session = local.java.session.getInstance(local.java.properties);

    local.java.store = createObject("Java","javax.mail.Store");
    local.java.store = local.java.session.getStore("imaps");
    local.java.store.connect(local.settings.server, local.settings.username, local.settings.password);

    local.java.folder  = local.java.store.getFolder("#local.settings.folder#");
    local.java.folder.open( local.java.folder.READ_ONLY );

    local.java.mailFlags = createObject("java", "javax.mail.Flags$Flag");
    local.java.mailFlagsSeen = createObject("java", "javax.mail.Flags").init(local.java.mailFlags.SEEN);
    local.java.mailFlagTerm = createObject("java", "javax.mail.search.FlagTerm").init(local.java.mailFlagsSeen, false);

    local.java.messages = local.java.folder.search(local.java.mailFlagTerm);

    /*This part could realy speed thinks up, but it does not work as expected*/
    /****************************
    local.java.profile = createObject("Java","javax.mail.FetchProfile");
    local.java.profileItem = createObject("Java","javax.mail.FetchProfile$Item");
    local.java.profile.add(local.java.profileItem.ENVELOPE);
    local.java.folder.fetch(local.java.messages, local.java.profile);
    ****************************/

    for(local.settings.x=1;local.settings.x<=arraylen(local.java.messages);local.settings.x=local.settings.x+1)
    {
        local.java.message =  local.java.messages[local.settings.x];
        WriteOutput(local.settings.x & ':' & GetTickCount()-local.settings.tick  & ':' & local.java.message.getSubject() & '<br>');
    }

    local.java.folder.close(true);
}
fecthImap();
</cfscript>
```